# C# Camera stream server with Console App using Raspberry Pi Raspberrian

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I can't find answer in Google and SoF. Is there any library which will allow me to build camera stream server streaming on localhost (or maybe internet)? Im using raspberrian, it is light weight system so i dont want to use WPF to do that. I want just simply server, and build client on another machine.

Comment: A localhost streaming server can hardly be lightweight... One generally pushes the stream to a remote server. Is this feasible for you?

Comment: Hmmm i think no. Except if i can write this second remote server. Now my raspberry not working with any job except clean system, so maybe it is not light weight, but will be good?

Comment: Maybe, depending on traffic. What protocol anyway? RTMP? RTSP?

Comment: @Attersson now i just started to research so protocol does not matter ;-)

Comment: I added an answer. But do you also need help with pushing your stream to the (local) server?

Comment: Propably, but i have to check SRS first, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

SRS could be a valid choice to set up a RTMP server: https://github.com/ossrs/srs

You would then need to push a stream to the server and the server will do the broadcasting.

Comment: To be clear, it is server so my role is to write application which just receiving data (Client) yes? If you can specify it in your answer it will be great.

Comment: Yes pretty much. Your live recorder client (or maybe not live), would need to push  the stream to the server. The server will then broadcast to subscribers.